# I am looking for a vegan substitute for cream cheese for use in a white chocolate/cream cheese icing

Tags: vegan, icing, cream-cheese

I tried one recipe with silken tofu, but it didn't set enough and just ran off the carrot cake.

Comment: Perhaps rather than substituting for the cream cheese specifically, you might try producing a recipe with the same rich creaminess and a touch of tang.  I would suggest a white chocolate ganache, using almond milk instead of cream, and a touch of lemon juice for the tang.  It would be completely vegan assuming you obtain vegan white chocolate.  Not putting this as an answer because I have never tried this--its just what my twisted brain came up with.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [tofutti](http://www.tofutti.com/) or [follow your heart](http://www.followyourheart.com/products/cream-cheese/) vegan cream cheeses which are excellent substitutes in terms of taste and texture. They work great in baked goods.

Answer (score 2):

I do like [lemontwist's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/30335/14918) for store bought options but would also suggest [this](http://www.healthfulpursuit.com/2012/12/how-to-make-soy-free-vegan-cream-cheese/) recipe as an at-home alternative. I have made it several times and find the consistency to be closer to the original cream cheese (as I remember it). Additionally I have used [this](http://www.egglesscooking.com/2012/08/28/vegan-carrot-cake-recipe/) vegan cream cheese recipe with the at-home cream cheese and it turned out amazing. Most of my friends could not tell the difference.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For ease, I agree with lemontwist: tofutti
For best all natural, nicoleeats as above.

Just to throw in a couple more...

yogurt cheese from favorite soy or coconuut yogurt: Stir in a bit of salt (sugar can also work but cheese is high in yummy sodium) and drain by cheese cloth or fine sieve a good long while.

Cheat: white frosting in a can (many are vegan) with a cube of fermented tofu (stinky but strong umami) from asian market. no one has ever found the resulting mix stinky at all -just the cheesiness comes through all the sugar.

Comment: I frequently use a bit of vegan yogurt stirred into a thick cashew cream to replace cream cheese. You get both the richness and the tang.